# creating dual layered x-axis in Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, javascript-objects, linechart

I would to build a line chart in javascript.

The challenge I am having is I cannot find documentation anywhere that shows me how to make my x-axis dual layered.

The two fields that would make up this x-axis are 'Month' and 'NumberofSurveys'

Comment: "like the below"...what?  Did you forget to insert a picture?  Is there any code you could insert to show how far you have gotten?

Comment: I do not have permission to upload a picture as I am new the forum.  I wish I were allowed to do b/c that would make my question easier to ask.    I don't want to two x-axis but I want a single x-axis with two layers ...

Comment: Score (plotted in line chart):    |   98.6 |    |   95.5 |  |   99.5 |  
X axis : layer 1 (month)           |  Jan   |    |  Feb   |  |  Mar   |          
X axis : layer 2  (NoOfSurvey) |    15  |     |    30  |   |    45   |

Comment: this is how it would like in excel: http://peltiertech.com/chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/